# Laravel webhook always returning '401 unauthorized' errors in production environment when receiving events from Stripe

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, stripe-payments, http-status-code-401

I am setting up a webhook in a Laravel project to receive events from stripe. When I configured stripe to send the webhook events to my local deployment of the website, everything worked fine. The webhook successfully handled all the sent events.


However, in the production environment, after setting up the webhook url in stripe, the url returns a `401 Unauthorized` error.

After some testing, it looked like stripe always gets a  `401 Unauthorized` error no matter the url, even when trying a non-existing one.


I am not using any authentication mechanism for this route, so no `auth:api` middleware.

Comment: Can you share more details about the endpoint and handler? This is difficult to answer effectively because we cannot know how or why your server is choosing to return a 401. What do your server logs say?

Comment: Did you figure this out?